# How to not get clicked when using Bluetooth barcode scanner of alert dialog buttons?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I use Cilico CT80 2D CMOS Barcode Scanner. It uses my physical keyboard as a default. When the alert dialog shows with positive and negative buttons it automatically presses the "left most" button after scanning a barcode. Every after scan it will virtually hit "enter".

Comment: Attaching the scanner as keyboard is a botch. Does it have other options?

Comment: I just want to know is there a way to disable the "Virtually Pressing" the screen when i scan the a barcode. It also selecting and pressing the apps when i am at the home page. @ND1010_

Comment: It automatically reads as Physical Keyboard "MTK BT HID" as default and the keyboard layout is also set on "Default"@Henry

Comment: @SauerVoussoir did you min that after dialog shows then automatically presses the "left most" button after scanning a barcode

Comment: The alert dialog already shown, after scanning a barcode it virtually clicks the "left most" button. @ND1010_

Comment: According to the manual it also supports USB serial port transmission mode. Using that may be more programming work for you but give a much better result.

Comment: @SauerVoussoir check with my answer

Comment: @SauerVoussoir Done ?

Comment: Not yet, kindly please read my other comments that was answered below to clearly understand what is my problem. @ND1010_

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced this issue.
You have to code on your focused `Edittext`

```
mEditText.setOnKeyListener((v, keyCode, event) -> {
            //for submiting result
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) &&
                    mEditText.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                // Your Positive button's code over here 
            }

            return false;
        });
```

Comment: I don't understand how it will be fixed. The alert dialog is already shown without any edit text was set on layout or setView. 

My problem is when after scanning a barcode and find a match there will be a new activity and it will show alert dialog. That's the time where the alert dialog were have been clicked by the barcode scanner.

I had fixed my problem by turning off the Bluetooth but i don't want to disconnect it.

Comment: Then you can change input method from the system after connecting device to Android. then Barcode won't fire enter automatically

Answer (score 0):

> How to access `AlertDailog` button programmetically and perform it's
>   click event

**Click button programmatically** by using  `yourButton.performClick()` method.

after your Scanning completed then call `.performClick()` of your `button`

Hope this will help you :-) happy coding......

**Edit**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
        builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
        builder.setTitle("Alert title");
        builder.setMessage("This is the example code snippet to perform click event of alert dialog button");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Perform click event programmatically", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        // DO TASK
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

        //Creating Button object for accessing it's click event or performing any kind of action
        Button PositiveButton = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        PositiveButton.performClick(); //calling performClick()  method to perform click event
    }
```

Comment: I cannot perform this kind of code in alert dialog.

Comment: @SauerVoussoir please edit your question and post question with your dialog code

Comment: @SauerVoussoir after scanning completed will start new activity and on that activity can open or show AlertDialog OK.......
.
.and you want to perform click event of AlertDialog (i.e OK button click event will be fired)

Comment: When i use the performClick the alertDialog won't show.

Comment: @SauerVoussoir AlertDialog can show but `PositiveButton.performClick();` event can fire istently that't why u can't see it